# asp.net subscription form writing to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Part of one of my assignments is to make a form that writes to a database when the user enters in the data. I've gotten so far but I'm getting a few errors. This is what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class subscribe_Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reg.Name = txtName.Text;
    reg.Age = txtAge.Text;
    reg.Sex = txtSex.Text;
    reg.Address = txtAddress.Text;
    reg.Email = txtEmail.Text;
    reg.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
    reg.InsertRegistration();
    phSuccess.Visible = true;
}

#region Methods
public void InsertRegistration()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegistrationInsert", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter parameterName = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    SqlParameter parameterAge = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    SqlParameter parameterSex = new SqlParameter("@Sex", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    SqlParameter parameterAddress = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    SqlParameter parameterEmail = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    SqlParameter parameterPhone = new SqlParameter("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    parameterName.Value = txtName;
    parameterAge.Value = txtAge;
    parameterEmail.Value = txtSex;
    parameterAddress.Value = txtAddress;
    parameterEmail.Value = txtEmail;
    parameterPhone.Value = txtPhone;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAge);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterSex);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAddress);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEmail);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterPhone);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
}

#endregion


namespace Registration
{
    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    #region Declarations
    Registration reg = new Registration();
    #endregion
}
}
```

I also have a class I made in a separate file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace Registration
{
public class Registration
{
    #region Declaration
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    #endregion
}


}
```

The errors I'm getting is

> the name reg does not exist in current context

Anyone could give me any pointers where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to create a instance of your `Registration` class. That's why it says name `reg` does not appear.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Add this part
    Registration reg = new Registration();

    reg.Name = txtName.Text;
    reg.Age = txtAge.Text;
    reg.Sex = txtSex.Text;
    reg.Address = txtAddress.Text;
    reg.Email = txtEmail.Text;
    reg.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
    reg.InsertRegistration();
    phSuccess.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, I added that now its saying 'Registration is a namespace but is used like a type'

Comment: As @Leopard suggests use `Registration.Registration reg = new Registration.Registration();` Didn't notice that you have a same name for the namespace also..

Comment: yeah that seemed to work Codelahiru. You guys are so helpful thanks so much, when I can I'll be sure to come back to help others.

Comment: Good to hear that. Help always. And make sure to mark @Leopard's answer as the correct answer.

Comment: I tried marking it as the correct answer but I need more reputation before I can mark it. It said it has been recorded. Thanks Codelahiru!!!

Answer (score 2):

The error is occuring in `Button1_Click`. You need to create an `object` of  `Registration` `class` in this method.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Registration.Registration reg = new Registration.Registration();    //Declare object of Registration class here
    reg.Name = txtName.Text;
    reg.Age = txtAge.Text;
    reg.Sex = txtSex.Text;
    reg.Address = txtAddress.Text;
    reg.Email = txtEmail.Text;
    reg.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
    reg.InsertRegistration();
    phSuccess.Visible = true;
}
```

Also you don't need this code.

```
namespace Registration
{
    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    #region Declarations
    Registration reg = new Registration();
    #endregion
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate that worked :) just a quick one its tellling me it "cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'int'. since age and phone number are int's

Comment: Use like this -   `reg.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);` and `reg.Phone =  Convert.ToInt32(txtPhone.Text);`

Comment: Thank you codelahiru I can't thank you enough you have saved me a lot of headaches. The response times from my trainers online is hours and its hard to get motivation to get back into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an *object* of  *Registration* class in *subscribe_Registration*

Comment: I declared the object in the partial class Registration?